# Play Video in javaFx

Tags: java, javafx

hello friends i want to play video in JavaFx i try below code

```
public class Video extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {



    String s=System.getProperty("/home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/Video/src"); 
    File f=new File(s, "/media/video.flv");
    Media m=new Media(f.toURI().toString());
    MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer(m);
    MediaView mv=new MediaView(mp);

    StackPane root=new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(mv);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root,400,400));
    stage.setTitle("Video");
    stage.show();
    mp.play();

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

and i get error like 
MediaException: MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE : /media/video.flv (No such file or directory)

which way i solve it?

Comment: /media/video.flv (No such file or directory), so you need to print the path of f, then check is there any problem with your code to obtain the file.

Comment: check whether your video.flv file exist in that path or the path is valid..

Comment: @meadlai:i try code with File f=new File("/home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/Video/src/media/video.flv") then after i get window Totally white means no video playing

Comment: Is your flv video vp6 encoded? Otherwise JavaFX won't play it.  Also add an [error handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaView.html#setOnError(javafx.event.EventHandler)) to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you set it explicitly when launching java, `String s=System.getProperty("/home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/Video/src");` will be null. So your code is equivalent to:

```
File f=new File("/media/video.flv");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    File f = new File("D:\\Project Files\\Videos\\Business\\Accounting\\Free\\Careers in Accounting.mp4");

    Media media = new Media(f.toURI().toString());
    MediaView mv = new MediaView();

    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(media);
    mv.setMediaPlayer(mp);
```

Comment: Hi, the only line relevant in your answer looks to be the last one. Also, you should post some explanation of why your code works.